# Highchart zooming bug?

Tags: highcharts, zooming

I have a scenario where a point does not render in zoomed-in mode. Wondering if it's a highchart bug or something I can do.

JSFiddle is here -- try zooming on the first point of series B (y value of 99.297). The chart zooms in but it seems like the focus is not in the right place

http://jsfiddle.net/HqMye/

Scatter chart with xy zoom; x axis is type datetime; series rendered in the scatterchart are as follows:

```
 var zoomSeries = [{
     name: "Series A",
     data: [
         [Date.parse("2013-05-16T11:01:25-04:00"), 99.75],
         [Date.parse("2013-05-14T10:18:41-04:00"), 99.5]
     ]
 }, {
     name: "Series B",
     data: [
         [Date.parse("2013-05-16T10:58:34-04:00"), 99.489],
         [Date.parse("2013-05-14T10:13:32-04:00"), 99.297]
     ]
 }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data should be sorted ascending by x.

Comment: Sebastian, I don't see this documented anywhere in the API but I tried it anyway. It fixes the zoom on the point I mentioned earlier but produces an odd behavior when you zoom on the second point of series B (the right-most one). I updated the JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/HqMye/3/. By sorting the data ascending I assume you meant within each series but let me know if I misunderstood.

Comment: Yes excaly, each series should be sorted, but I'm not sure how can I reproduce problem with series B? Which steps should I do, and what is wrong

Comment: Thanks -- if you're affiliated with the project it would be great if the sorting detail can be added here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series -- seems pretty important.Also, to reproduce the new issue, zoom onto the black point of series B to the right (y value of 99.489 in the updated jsFiddle -- the zoom works but you will see that one of the series A points is still lingering on the chart to the left. Zoom on other single points seems to zoom onto that point alone

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is Highcharts bug.

You can fix this by adding min to yAxis. http://jsfiddle.net/yevkim/ujj2f/
for example:

```
yAxis: {
   min:99.2
}
```

Comment: Thank you -- this works and I might use it if I don't get a better answer. I prefer to avoid this as Highcharts seems to do a pretty good job calculating the min/max points(and per API doc states it would auto-calculate min)...